# Функция для вычисления длины массива в Си

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Я знаю что длину массива можно вычислить при помощи `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`. Я попытался написать следующею функцию:

```
int arrayLenght(int array[]) {
    return sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

но она возвращает единицу. Если изменить тип с int на size_t или unsigned int ничего не изменится. Также передавал массив как указатель, но как я и думал, ничего не изменилось. Функция возвращает число 1.

Comment: Ее не существует.

Comment: Массивы как аргумент в функцию не передаются. Приходит в функцию только указатель на первый элемент. Количество элементов забота программиста как передать.

Answer (score 2):

в С++ для массивов есть std::vector, в результате не надо думать о длине, ее можно получить через метод `.size()`

ну а в C как вы думаете почему функции работы с последовательностями требуют 2 параметра - указатель на последовательность и размер последовательности?

потому что в C нет функции для вычисления размера произвольной последовательности

исключение - строки, которые обязаны заканчиваться на `'\0'` и размер строки определяется так - начиная с 0 позиции от указателя строки ищется `'\0'` и определяется как далеко он находится - это и есть длина строки

если вы посмотрите что выдается на `sizeof(array)`, то скорее всего 4 - размер указателя, а `array[0]` - это `int` и его размер тоже 4, вот и получаете в итоге 1

но если вы сделаете

```
char array[]
```

то предположу (могу и ошибаться), что размер массива будет... 4 (4 / 1)